# Error when trying to display grayscale image converted from rgb

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm doing a project in deeplearning where I'll train a classifier using the SVHN dataset.

Initially, I had train_images and test_images with shapes (73257, 32, 32, 3) and (26032, 32, 32, 3), respectively and they are normally displayed using plt.imshow().

I converted the images to greyscale using the following code:

```
f = lambda img: tf.expand_dims(np.average(img, axis=-1), axis=-1).numpy()

train_images = f(train_images)
test_images = f(test_images)
```

I tried, as well:

```
train_images = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(train_images).numpy()
test_images = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(test_images).numpy()
```

On both cases, the output gives images with shape (32, 32, 1) as items in each of the train_images, test_images - the new shapes are, therefore, (73257, 32, 32, 3) and (26032, 32, 32, 1), respectively.

But, for some reason, when I try to display these new greyscale images, I get the following error : `TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data.`

I have no idea why.

Comment: You could leave out `tf.expand_dims` to get 32x32 arrays.  And then display them with `imshow(...., cmap='Greys')`

Comment: The thing is that I need to maintaing that last dimension as a requirement of the assignment.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following function for transforming to grayscale:

```
f = lambda img: np.mean(img, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
```

Then displayed the image using:

```
img = np.squeeze(array)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')
```

Where array is any item on train_images or test_images.